# Does TFS 'keep local version' change the file's history?

Tags: tfs

If I have files checked out and run an update later, I'll usually come across a conflict which gives me a few options to resolve. If I pick the 'keep local version' option, do my changes replace the server's version without updating the history?

Is there a reason why you would want an option to alter your source code so secretly?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing changes until you check in the file and you will always have the history and annotations.

Typically unless you have a good reason not to you will want to merge conflicted non-binary files and use common sense when choosing whether to take an updated binary file or not. If it is a non-binary merge pretty much the only time you would keep local is if you specifically knew you didn't want the latest changes since you check the file out to make it in to your copy.

Answer (score 1):

When merging, everything happens on your PC - *nothing* is checked in to the server.

You have three options:

- Keep the server version. This is very much like an "undo checkout" and it overwrites your local copy with the server's version of the file so your local changes are lost.
- Keep the local version. This ignores what is on the server and keeps the version on your PC, so your local changes are preserved.
- Merge. This allows you to use a diff/merge process to pick and choose text lines from your source file and the server's source file, which allows you (a) to see exactly what has changed in both versions, and (b) decide what the final result should be (all the server's changes, all of your changes, or (usually) some hybrid mixture of both of them.

After you merge, if you have used either of the options that will alter your local copy, you really ought to rebuild your project and check that the changes introduced have not broken your code. You can then continue your work and check in when you are confident that everything is working.

The best approach to use with source control is to aim to make small self-contained modifications that you can check-in frequently (e.g. once or twice a day). Similarly (after checking that the net code is safe to take, e.g. with continuous integration), get the latest code fairly often (after every check-in, and preferably no less than once a day). This team strategy minimises the chance of your changes clashing with those of another developer and a merge being required. In the cases where a clash does occur, it is generally quick and easy to resolve because you are taking small bites of the code frequently, rather than working "offline" for weeks and waiting for thousands of changes to build up on the server. Merges are often complicated and difficult, so choosing strategies that minimise the need to merge can be a very beneficial approach.